# json compatibility issue on aarch64 GNU/Linux

Tags: c++, linux, arm64, jsoncpp

I have been facing issues while reading file on ARM64 based system as file is getting truncated and able to read partially only. I am able to read the file properly on linux x8664 .

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <json/json.h>

int main()
{

    Json::Reader reader;
    Json::Value root;
    std::string filePath = "/usr/data/signature.json";

    // Read the JSON content from the file
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ifstream::binary);
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filePath << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    bool parsing = reader.parse(file, root, false);

    if (!parsing)
    {
        // report to the user the failure and their locations in the document.
        std::cout << reader.getFormatedErrorMessages()
                  << "\n";
    }

    // Extract the signature value from the JSON
    std::string signature = root["signature"].asString();

    std::cout << "size = " << signature.size() << std::endl;

    // Print the extracted signature
    std::cout << "Signature string: " << signature << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the signature json file contents:

```
{
    "signature": "3045022100c8365fbdb1c9a54ffa537c52a82d7168887912e23eeed2eacf045e517d08b1f7022033d3dc6a7bd30b8ee7ab652a2522348137d3e48d86a80e68038bd19cd0eae200"
}
```

and here is the output which i get on aarch64 linux ;

```
Signature string: 3045022100c8365fbdb1c9a54ffa537c52a82d7168887912e23eeed2eacf045e517d08b1f7022033d3dc6a7bd30b8ee7ab652a2522348137d3e48d86a0
```

which is different of json file in terms of number of character is printed on console but size is same (142) and this issue is observed on aarch64 GNU/Linux. Any pointers how to troubleshoot this as it looks architecture dependent behavior as Linux x8664 it works fine.
so basically problem is string size is coming properly but content which it display it is not complete and when I used this content to verify the signature it didn't work as string should content complete content as kept inside signature.json file. I am not sure how aarch64 is having limit of character to show though printed size is accurate. It looks architecture issue to me as same code work on x8664 linux.  Now how to update this code to work properly on aarch64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: If the length of the string is correct, then perhaps it's the terminal that doesn't show it correctly? How many characters wide is your terminal window? Do you get a horizontal scrollbar to scroll the text from side to side in your terminal?

Comment: It is not terminal issue as it looks string contains blank character after that as required character to complete the string is not present there and instead of this other hidden characters available there .

Comment: I have printed size of string after printing the contents and it is showing proper size but content is not displayed properly and it added additional content 8  instead of 0 so actual string is having sequence of 48d86a8 but in output you can see 48d86a0 and after that noting gets printed .

Comment: Can you please resize your terminal window to become a little smaller, then take a screenshot of it and [edit] your question to show it? With the actual (wrong) output of course.

Comment: it shows exactly like this :content size =142
content=3045022100c8365fbdb1c9a54ffa537c52a82d7168887912e23eeed2eacf045e517d08b1f7022033d3dc6a7bd30b8ee7ab652a2522348137d3e48d86a80e68038bd10
after this noting is visible.

Comment: `how to troubleshoot` Create an minimal [MCVE]. _Remove_ parts of your code _until_ you are able to reproduce it with the _smallest_ possible set of inputs. `able to read partially only` Can you _read_ the content of the file fully and correct without any json? Does it work with json content statically into the source code? Does it work with `printf`? What happens if you show _last_ 6 characters of the string? Does it work with smaller json? Does it work with `{"a":"b"}`?`{"a":"bc"}`..?  `it looks architecture dependent behavior` What compiler, compiler version, compiler options are you using?

Comment: yes it works with smaller contents till 30 character and there is no issue.I have shared minimal reproducible example only. without json also issue persist and tried to read simple  signature.txt file and observed the same behaviour . Is it related with memory buffering issue on aarch64.   it supports c++14 and boost 1-61 version on gcc compiler. we are using here linaro6.5 tool chain for cross compilation.